# Getting "undefined" when adding an object to a new string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects (student name, achievement, etc..) and I want to add any object that has the name "Jody" (for example) in a new empty array I created.
However, when I try to print the name only of the new array of objects I get the `undefined`. 
Note: I can't use let, const etc..

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

```
var student;
var newStudents = [];
var students = [{
    name: 'Odelia',
    track: 'Accounting',
    achievements: '26',
    points: '2260'
}, {
    name: 'Jody',
    track: 'Web Design',
    achievements: '12',
    points: '890'
}, {
    name: 'Yann',
    track: 'Javascript',
    achievements: '10',
    points: '2266'
}, {
    name: 'Max',
    track: 'Marketing',
    achievements: '13',
    points: '1010'
}, {
    name: 'Jody',
    track: 'iOS',
    achievements: '9',
    points: '1002'
}, ]

for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    student = students[i];
    if (student.name === 'Jody') {
        newStudents.push(student);
    }
}

console.log(newStudent.name);
```

**output:**

```
    0: 
      achievements: "12"
      name: "Jody"
      points: "890"
      track: "Web Design"
      __proto__: Object
    1: 
      achievements: "9"
      name: "Jody"
      points: "1002"
      track: "iOS"
      __proto__: Object
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array(0)

    undefined
```

Comment: Yep - that code works fine.

Comment: Should be `console.log(newStudent[0].name);` Because newStudent is a array

Comment: Is `console.log(newStudent.name);` a typo? The array is called `newStudents`, plural. If that's what you meant, then it's undefined because arrays don't have a `name` property.

Comment: yes guys sorry a typo from newStudent to newStudents with an s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should be `newStudents`not  `newStudent`

```
    console.log(newStudents[0].name);
```

Also,`newStudents` is Array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print name outside of the loop. Cross check it again.

It should be like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    student = students[i];
    console.log(newStudent.name);
    if (student.name === 'Jody') {
        newStudents.push(student);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's work for me;

```
const students    = [
    {
        name:         'Odelia',
        track:        'Accounting',
        achievements: '26',
        points:       '2260',
    },
    {
        name:         'Jody',
        track:        'Web Design',
        achievements: '12',
        points:       '890',
    },
    {
        name:         'Yann',
        track:        'Javascript',
        achievements: '10',
        points:       '2266',
    },
    {
        name:         'Max',
        track:        'Marketing',
        achievements: '13',
        points:       '1010',
    },
    {
        name:         'Jody',
        track:        'iOS',
        achievements: '9',
        points:       '1002',
    },
];

const newStudents = [];
for ( const student of students ) {
    if ( student.name === 'Jody' ) {
        newStudents.push( student );
    }
}
```

Or you can use filter :

```
const newStudents = students.filter( student => student.name === 'Jody' );
```

Answer (score 0):

@Yann Bohbot,

There are 2 issues,
1. Put correct object name i.e. "newStudents" and NOT "newStudent" in console.log();
2. You need to change below line to get values,
console.log(newStudents[1].name);

Your are using multidimensional array and need iterate in proper way... :)